# Double click event for grid view item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there is any way to get grid view item after double click. I have not found double click event in metro gird view. Only events like `ItemClick` and `PointerPressed` are there. Any suggestion?

```
<GridView Name="downloadGrid"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CollectionItems}}"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" PointerPressed="downloadGrid_PointerPressed"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewItemStyle}" 
          Width="Auto" SelectionChanged="downloadGrid_SelectionChanged">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="6" Height="280" Width="200">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Path=Type, Converter={StaticResource Icon}}" MaxWidth="20" MinWidth="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF017DD5" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="11" Margin="3,0,0,0" Height="Auto"/>
                <ProgressBar Grid.Row="2" Value="{Binding Path=PercentOfCompletion, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}}" Width="75" Height="11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#FF78D200" Margin="3,0,0,0">
                    <ProgressBar.BorderBrush>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF78D200"/>
                    </ProgressBar.BorderBrush>
                </ProgressBar>
                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=PercentOfCompletion, Converter={StaticResource ProgressConverter}}" Margin="-15,0,15,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Foreground="#333333" FontSize="12"/>-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=StatusInfo}" Style="{StaticResource MainPageTextStyle}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                <Button x:Name="playNow" Grid.Row="3" Content="Play Now" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource DownloadButtonStyle}" Click="playNow_Click" Margin="3,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPlay}"/>
                <Button x:Name="pauseResumeBUtton" Grid.Row="3" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource DownloadButtonStyle}" Click="pauseResumeBUtton_Click" Margin="0,4,3,2" IsEnabled="{Binding IsResume}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Size: " Style="{StaticResource MainPageTextStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=OriginalFileSize, Converter={StaticResource FileSizeConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource MainPageTextStyle}" Margin="0,9,5,6"/>
                <!--<TextBlock Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Output: " Style="{StaticResource MainPageTextStyle}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="iPhone / iPod" Foreground="#FF017DD5" FontSize="12" Margin="0,2,5,0"/>-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: show your grid or something u have

Comment: Isn't there Double Tapped event?

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** with using a `Tapped` (or `DoubleTapped`) event is that these events only fire when it detects a Tap gesture. *"Well, yeah. That's exactly what I want"*, you may say.

**Buuuuuut** if you are using a mouse and you click on your item and the mouse moves a little bit (or a lot) before you release your finger, then that event is **not** recognized as a Tap. So that event **will not fire**. This can lead to the user not understanding why his clicks are not being recognized. This can be reproduced easily and consistently.

### Potential Hacky Solution

The only way I can currently think of implementing what you would to do is by using the `ItemClick` event. When a `GridViewItem` is clicked, start a timer. The next time the `ItemClick` event fires, check if the same item was clicked within a reasonable amount of time (500ms? Less? I'm sure this is a quick Google away).

Of course you have to make sure you take care of stopping the timer and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As VasileMarianFălămaș wrote in the comments to your question you can use the double tapped event.

however you should question yourself if you want double tap events on a grid item. One of the best Windows 8 features is that app apps function the same way. Users shouldn't have to think if they should double tap or just tap in this application.

What action do you want to do when double tapping? opening the item? this is normally done by single tap.

here is an overview of when which gestures are used in Windows 8 apps:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761498.aspx

Comment: I would not recommend DoubleTapped if you'd like your app to play nice when used with a mouse.